# upgrade to postgres 14 from postgres 13 using pg_basebackup

Tags: postgresql, backup, upgrade

I want to upgrade/move a running timescale cluster manage by Patroni using PostgreSQL 13 to a new hardware with PostgreSQL 14, the dataset is ~ 40GB but is taking ages take a backup using:

```
pg_dump -j 8 -Fd -f /tmp/promscale.back -v promscale
```

Same if using `ts-dump`

Therefore wondering if I could use  `pg_basebackup`? Currently I am trying something like:

```
pb_basebackup -h 10.1.2.3 -U replicator -P -D /db/data14 -S slot1 -X stream --checkpoint=fast
```

But I only get this and no progress:

```
waiting for checkpoint
```

Any idea about how could I speed the dump or upgrade with the minimum zero downtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `pg_basebackup` to upgrade. You have to use `pg_upgrade`. Have you tried reading the documentation?

Comment: Hi, I did but since sing `pg_dump` is extremely slow I thought that I could become a replica using a major version (like the in the mysql/maria world), If I am understanding what I could do Is replicate to the same version `13` and then locally do the `pg_upgrade` right?

Comment: Why replicate for that?

Comment: Because I am moving to new hardware or you are suggesting to upgrade first to `14` and then replicate for moving to the new hardware?

Comment: Either way should work - but that's unrelated to the upgrade performance.

Comment: In Postgres is it possible to add a replica with a major version? for example master with version 13 and replica with 14?

Comment: No, that is not possible with streaming replication, only with logical replication.

Answer (score 1):

From the manual:

> At the beginning of the backup, a checkpoint needs to be performed on the source server. This can take some time (especially if the option --checkpoint=fast is not used), during which pg_basebackup will appear to be idle.